# Finding the range of a 3x2 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

How would you go about finding the range of a matrix like:

$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    2 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$

This one is confusing me because it maps to the third dimension while only having two column vectors, I'm thinking its a plane but how would you explicitly state what the range is?

Comment: We need to prove the the column vectors of the matrix are linearly independent, that is that the matrix has rank=2. Then the range is the plane spanned by the column vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that matrix maps from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

To determine the range, by RREF or by determinants, we can find that the matrix has rank $2$ and then the range is a subspace of dimension $2$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is the plane

$$\pi:s\begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    2  \\
    0  \\
    \end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}
     0 \\
     1 \\
     1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: You're right, my mistake

Comment: @A-X You are welcome! Can you check that the matrix has rank=2?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with that term. I've only covered row reduction, matrix products, linear independence, and linear transformations. Is calculating the range beyond the scope of what I've covered?

Comment: @A-X RREF stands for row reduction echelon form! If you apply that you'l find 2 pivots and thus the column vectors are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

Setting $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    2 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 2},$$
we have $\operatorname{rank}(A)=2$ if and only if there exists a $2\times 2$ submatrix of $A$ with determinant unequal to zero. We have 3 candidates here:

1. first and second row
2. first and third row
3. second and third row.

While any of these candidates work, easiest is candidate 2: the identity matrix with determinant 1. Thus, we have $\operatorname{rank}(A)=2.$